# python dictionary string operations

Tags: python, string, dictionary, operations

Currently I have my data in a directory

```
myDict = {'a':'Andy','b':'Bill','c':'Carly' }
```

I want to achieve something like

```
input = a --> output = Andy

input = ab --> output = Andy Bill

input = abc --> output = Andy Bill Carly
```

How can I do that ? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def girdi_al():
    isim = input("isim giriniz: ")
    return isim

def isim_donustur(isim):
    cikti = isim()

    donusum = {'a':'Ankara','b':'Bursa','c':'Ceyhan'}

    string = ''

    for char in cikti:
        string += donusum[char] + ' '

    print(string )

def main():
    isim_donustur(girdi_al)

# === main ===
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate through the individual letters of the input string.
- Look up each item in the dictionary.
- Concatenate the results as you go.

Can you handle each of those capabilities?  If not, please post your best attempt and a description of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for comment.

I want you to give this output:

isim giriniz: ab
çıktı: Ankara Bursa

Or;

isim giriniz: ac
çıktı: Ankara Ceyhan

Answer (score 1):

`isim` is not a function, and all you need to do is access that key in the dictionary

```
def girdi_al():
    isim = input("isim giriniz: ")
    return isim

def isim_donustur(isim):
    cikti = isim

    donusum = {'a':'Ankara','b':'Bursa','c':'Ceyhan'}

    #How can I do?
    result = []
    for letter in cikti:
        result.append(donusum[cikti])
    print(' '.join(result))


def main():
    isim_donustur(girdi_al)

# === main ===
main()
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, what if `isim` is equal to `'abc'`? Your code doesn't handle multiple keys.

Comment: @GBlomqvist oh that was embarassing. Thank you for pointing it out. Modified the code now.

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this

```
myDict = {'a':'Andy','b':'Bill','c':'Carly' }
input_str = "abc"

" ".join([v for k,v in myDict.items() if k in list(input_str)])
```